# Excel formula to compute the time Of "Logoff" record and its nearest "Logon" record above

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: LogOn LogOff Sample]

I would like to have a 3rd column that only shows the time duration if the 2nd column value is "PC LogOff". The time duration will get the 1st instance of "PC LogOn" before the "PC LogOff" occurred. Is this possible in Excel?

Comment: If you have Excel 365, one way is to use reverse lookup with xlookup.

Answer (score 2):

`XLOOKUP()` will give you desired result.

```
=IF(B1="PC LogOf",A1-XLOOKUP("PC LogOn",$B$1:$B1,$A$1:$A1,0,0,-1),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have XLOOKUP, in C2 put `=IF(B2="PC LogOn",A2,C1)` and drag down, with C1 being just `=A1`.
Then in D1 put `=IF(B1="PC LogOff",A1-C1,"")` and drag down.